# Seconds Behind Master in Cloud Service

Tags: mysql, replication

I have few mysql servers in replication master-salves in cloud service.

The problem is even thought all configuration, mysql versions, server's resources are the same, still I have inconsistency in slave's behavior.

For example, I have a set of stable mysql slaves which work perfectly, and a set of unstable slaves which still have seconds behind master even in idle mode, without traffic, and the set of unstable is always the same servers.

I am looking for something that is different in stable and unstable slaves. So far I didn't find something like this. Please, if you know how to find the thing that different share this with us.

Thanks.

Comment: How high is Seconds_Behind_Master on any given unstable server?

Comment: Seconds_Behind_Master is around 20-50 all the time

Comment: Are the OS clocks sync'd between master and slave ???

Comment: There was a difference of 3 sec, now there are completely synced, still I have spikes on slave

Comment: Have you ever erased the relay logs on the Slave before ???

Comment: Are the traceroutes from the Master to all Slaves the same ???

Comment: No, the replication was established a week ago by copying raw data as many stable slave servers.

Comment: Is there high write load on the Master ?

Comment: traceroutes are not the same, traceroute to the troublesome server is much longer and ping is as much as 3 times than ping to normal server. Ping flood without losses. Looks like network issues.

Comment: Regarding high load, I don't know, it's master on the second level of masterts, I wish I have a log of all replication queries, but there is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all clocks are sync'd, I would suspect high write load on the Master. Why?

The Master is responsible for doing two things:

1. Executing the SQL
2. Recording the SQL and its timestamp

If there is any intermittency between steps 1 and 2, this could account for what seems to be replication lag.

Since there are stable servers, I suggest resetting the relay logs on the unstable servers by doing the following:

- STOP SLAVE;
- SHOW SLAVE STATUS\G
- Get LOGFIL from `Relay_Master_Log_File`
- Get LOGPOS from `Exec_Master_Log_Pos`
- CHANGE MASTER TO master_log_file='LOGFIL',master_log_pos=LOGPOS;
- START SLAVE;

The CHANGE MASTER TO command erases the relay logs it currently has and starts fresh.

Give it a Try, and see if this clears up the replication lag !!!

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, also I'll take a look at network. Thanks again